# Run a Ruby Command Line Application from Java

Tags: java, ruby, unit-testing, amazon-s3, jruby

I would like to be able to run a command line interface `Ruby` application from `Java`. I want to do this so I can start and stop [FakeS3](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3) (a light weight S3 server) before and after some tests, in order to test some code that uses the `Java AWS SDK`. The tests must be able to run from my machine, as well as on `Jenkins` build machies

The requirements are:

1. Cannot require any changes to the system it is running on (installing applications, reconfiguring system settings etc not allowed)
2. Platform independent

I've tried out a couple of options but yet to succeed:

1. [**Run using jruby**](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyAndJavaCodeExamples#java-calling-jruby) - I've tried calling evalScript on various different script files in the project, but I always end getting an exception saying files that were included using `require` could not be found. I can't find any examples of running Ruby scripts that are not contained within one file, and don't know how to tell the runtime about paths to include
2. [**Compile with rubyflux**](https://github.com/headius/rubyflux) - Again, tried to compile several files, but the Java code it generates is always the same and doesn't really do anything

Are there any simpler solutions I could try out, or anything I could do to make one of these approaches work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is with jruby. You just need to configure the load path to do this.

```
ScriptingContainer sc = new ScriptingContainer();
sc.setLoadPaths(Arrays.asList("folder1", "folder2"));

File server = new File("server.rb");
sc.runScriptlet(new FileReader(server), server.getName());
```